# Python can't set attribute due to property conflict

Tags: python, constructor, attributes, decorator

I have following code:

```
class T: 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = None

    @property
    def age(self):
        return 30

t = T('j')
```

when I create object t, it'll have error `AttributeError: can't set attribute 'age'`.

I understand here with `@property`, actually `self._name` is created for the object. So `self._name` will be in conflict with `self.name`?

Or if I'm wrong, then what's causing the conflict here?

Comment: "I understand here with @property, actually self._name is created for the object" - no, nothing like that happens. If you wanted that to happen, you would have to write code to do that.

Comment: Then can I ask what's causing the name conflict here?

Comment: You're trying to set `self.age`, but you did not define a setter for the `age` property - you have not defined what setting `self.age` actually means.